# Material Design headerbar and icons color

Tags: website-design, color, icon

I'm trying to design a website using the Material Design guidelines.

I've a navbar/headerbar with the logo of my website and some icons.
The background color is transparent, showing the background image, when the scroll position is on top of the page.
When the scroll position is almost 400px, it is dark grey (it fades during the entire 400pxs).

As you can see, the background has some white spikes, so I can't use white icons. But if I use black or dark icons, they are not well visible when the background is dark grey.

What Material Design guidelines say about this kind of problem? I've read I can't use a shadow to make the top of the background darker...

Relevant documentation:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/imagery.html#imagery-ui-integration

(text protection paragraph)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make the transparent bar have a background of black but instead have the opacity set to 20%. Then you could use off white icons and text. Try using Ghostwhite or something like that, since white on black is quite harsh.

You can still have the fade until 400px too. But it will be much smoother.

Comment: I can add a protection scrim but with a maximum opacity of 40% (according to bigG guidelines), the icons must have 80% opacity (again second bigG) and the result would be this one... http://i.imgur.com/XT0NIij.png  I'm not sure them are enough visible

Comment: That looks alot better, what about using the purple color for the icons, similar to the background?

Comment: I need to follow the material design guidelines... icons can be black or white.

Comment: Then you will have to rethink your design :)

Comment: I can't belive material design does not have a solution to use white backgrounds with dark interface, there must be one...

Comment: Why do you want the interface at the top to be transparent? you could make it white and then fade to black at 400px. That gives a nice UX and still preserves some of your look and feel. Or you could move the icons over a little so they're not on top of the white in the background.

Comment: it must be transparent because I'm trying to follow the material design guidelines... if you have no experience with them please don't reply

Answer (score 0):

Could you have the icons fade between the two colors as the background fades? This could be a simple CSS animation class (highly suggested) or anything as complicated as you want.

Comment: currently this is my solution but it does not feel material design at all..

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you want to hear, but according to the google guidelines, you really shouldn't be using an image in the header.

You can use a color overlay on your photos to make the text pop. But if the text or icons don't pop on the image you're using, then you should probably be using an image that works better, or a solid color.

If I were you, I'd use a solid color.